# SUM all fields have a same type value sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have a table and i want statistics price of type a and type c as SELL, type b and type d as BUY by day  the result like

```
 Table :
   | Name |   type  |   price  |   day       |
   | n1   |   a     |     1    |2013-10-10   |
   | n2   |   b     |     2    |2013-10-10   |
   | n3   |   c     |     3    |2013-10-10   |
   | n4   |   d     |     4    |2013-10-10   |
   | n1   |   a     |     5    |2013-11-10   |
   | n2   |   b     |     6    |2013-11-10   |
   | n3   |   c     |     7    |2013-11-10   |
   | n4   |   d     |     8    |2013-11-10   |
```

and i want result like this

```
|  DAY       |    SELL (price a+price c)   |   BUY (price b +price d) |
|2013-10-10  |       4                     |         6                |
|2013-11-10  |       12                    |         14               |
```

Here my code

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_mysp]
@starttime datetime,
 @endtime datetime  
 as
   DECLARE @TIME DATETIME
   SET @TIME=@ENDTIME-@STARTTIME 
   SELECT  (table.day) AS DAY ,  case BUY
   WHEN TABLE.TYPE ='a' or TABLE.TYPE = 'c' THEN SUM (price) end,
   CASE SELL 
   WHEN TABLE.TYPE = 'b' or TABLE.TYPE = 'd' THEN SUM (price) end,

      FROM TABLE WHERE TABLE.DAY>@starttime AND TABLE.TIME<@ENDTIME
      order by TABLE.DAY


GO
```

I can't sum( type a and type c), sum (type b and type d) as i want, it only can sum by type a with a, b with b......
and i get result like

```
 |  DAY       |    SELL (price a+price c)   |   BUY (price b +price d) | 
 | 2013-10-10 |         1                   |       NULL               |
 | 2013-10-10 |         3                   |       NULL               |
 | 2013-10-10 |         NULL                |       2                  |
 | 2013-10-10 |         NULL                |       4                  |
 | 2013-11-10 |         5                   |       NULL               |
 | 2013-11-10 |         7                   |       NULL               |
 | 2013-11-10 |        NULL                 |       6                  |
 | 2013-11-10 |        NULL                 |       8                  |
```

any sugesstion for me ?
sorry for my terrible english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TRY THIS**

I don't see time in your table but i guess the column DAY is in date format

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_mysp]
@starttime datetime,
 @endtime datetime  
 as     
SELECT [Day],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'a' OR [Type] = 'c' THEN price ELSE 0.00 END) SELL,
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'b' OR [Type] = 'd' THEN price ELSE 0.00 END) BUY
FROM    [TABLE]
WHERE   [Day] BETWEEN @starttime AND @endtime
GROUP BY    [Day]
```

Comment: thks but its not work, it still sum only same type (a to a, b to b), it cant sum (type a and type c ) although they have same day

Comment: did you try to execute this against your database?

Comment: oh,my bad, i dont recognize have "GROUP BY TYPE, DAY" in my code.... it should only "GROUP BY DAY".. thks you so much :D

Comment: Ok that's great! But you made me crazy... :)

Comment: my bad, im sorry :D hehe, im sure im will vote for u when i got 15 reputation :D

Answer (score -2):

I think your

```
TABLE.TYPE ='a' or TABLE.TYPE = 'c'
```

should be

```
TABLE.TYPE ='a' AND TABLE.TYPE = 'c'
```

That way, it will only sum IF both are what you need.

Comment: not work, result return = 0 (because type of any name just can be "a" or "b" or "c" or "d"